# memory cost for using functions as members while calling a function

Tags: function, arguments

it's my first post here.

I know that the question may seem vague i'll try to be clear...

globally without targeting any interpreted language (well i'm using C# currently but i think the answer should work for others too...)

I wonder, does this type of call :

```plain
Afunction(var1,var2,AnotherFunction(var3,var2,AthirdFunction(Avector.z)),Mathf.RoundToInt(Avector.x));
```

Will run faster than :

```plain
Type var1 = avalue;
Type var2 = avalue;
Type var3 = avalue;
Type var4 = AthirdFunction(Avector.z);
Type var5 = Mathf.RoundToInt(Avector.x);
Type var6 = AnotherFunction(var3,var2,var4);

Afunction(var1,var2,var6,var5);
```

I know that the second way is easier to read, but does it runs faster, knowing that i'll probably call this function extensively (lets say, in a graphic app, every frame). 
And about memory use, is it better to create more variables to destroy it right after using the function, or to directly code everything inside "Afunction" while declaring as less variables as possible...

(and for understanding : `Afunction(), AnotherFunction() and AthirdFunction()` are already declared somewhere else)

I hope this type of question is not outside of the forum rules of use...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a reasonable compiler, the algorithms you use in Afunction, AnotherFunction, and AthirdFunction have way more impact on performance than anything else that you asked above.  Generally you worry about what you've asked once you have the most efficient function possible.

Plus, compilers will inline function calls which means that you may call

```
return_value = fx( A(), B() );
```

But if you were to look at what passes for assembler output for your compiler, things may not look that way.

There is overhead with invoking a function call, and it is system and compiler architecture that dictates what that overhead will be.

If this were an interpreted language like awk or BASIC, then the second code block, calling things outside a function linearly, will run faster.  Or more correctly it did back in 1980's on DEC PDP's.

Comment: Actually i was thinking more about a case where Afunction, AnotherFunction, and AthirdFunction are simple tasks functions like finding a local position from a world position, but still, each of those actions needs reading and comparing variables from many object, and/or creating local variables for iteration purpose or simple calculus tasks...

of course if those functions were much more complex, there would be a good reason to store their own results in local variables before passing it as argument.

What i was wondering was when should we go from the first style to the other style?

Comment: and is there a good reason which justify the use of the "all in one line without storing results of secondary functions in local variables before" (i started to wonder this because i want to improve my own coding style before going further on my project because i would'nt like to face execution speed problems when i'll be half way to the project...)

As a good reason for me is speed/readability/reusability ratio

Comment: IMO one of the big reasons to use functions is the DRY principle. Don't Repeat Yourself.  The means relegate one job to only one function. For example, in legacy code we have multiple places that find tomorrow's date, and they are different. Unless you are working in something like an ARM (embedded) system, worry more about correctness, and maintainability (DRY fits here).  Code written in functions does not have to "stay" in the function in the executable. Write code that anyone can read, single functions that go on for screen after screen are difficult for the next guy to read and understand